# How to clear ASP.NET cache thread-safely?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

In my project I have some cached values implemented using singleton pattern - it looks like this:

```
Roles GetRoles
{
get{
         var cached = HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"];
         if(cached == null){
             cached = new GetRolesFromDb(...);
         }
         return cached as Roles;
   }
}
```

When I change the roles I'm clearing the cache (iterating over all keys).
I think it isn't thread-safe - if some request tries to get cached roles, 
cached != null and meanwhile cache had been cleared GetRoles returns null.

Comment: Is this your actual code? As shown here, `GetRoles` will only return null if either *(1)* `Cache["key"]` returns a non-null object that can't be converted to the `Roles` type, or *(2)* `Cache["key"]` returns null and the `GetRolesFromDb` type can't be converted to the `Roles` type. There's no thread-safety ssue evident in the code you've shown us.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Cache` is inherently thread safe. You don't need to do anything in order to be safe. Yes, if you want to prevent multiple loads, you do the locking on load. But you can remove at any time. And load too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private object lockRoles = new object();

public Roles GetRoles
{
  get 
  {
    object cached = HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"];
    if(cached == null) 
    {
      lock(lockRoles)
      {
        cached = HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"];
        if (cached == null) 
        {
          cached = new GetRolesFromDb(...);
          HttpContext.Current.Cache["key"] = cached; 
        }
      }
    }
    return (Roles)cached;
  }
}    

public void ClearRoles()
{
  HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("key");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but it's not thread-safe - let's say cached != null in both checking (cache==null) moments - and has been cleared just before return (Roles)cached

Comment: @Pavel - it does not matter when the cache item is cleared (by another thread). The idea of cached data is that at any moment it may or may not be in the cache. If it is there - good, it is returned. If it is not - it is retrieved from storage, put in the cache and returned. If it is removed from the cache between the moment it is put in the cache and it is returned - not a problem, it will be retrieved and cached again the next time you call `GetRoles`.